# Is it possible to have className intellisence in VS2015 for strongly typed react.js components (TSX files)?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, classname, tsx

When one writes plain HTML file (or Razor CSHTML) in Visual Studio, VS gives a nice intellisence for CSS classes (`<div class="....intellisence..."/>`) found in css files attached to the project.

Is something like this possible in TSX (`<div className="???"/>`)?

Comment: This works for me in VS2015.3 as long as the CSS definitions are included in the project.